# Do I have to cover the entire floor while painting a ceiling, or can I simply cover the floor in the area I'm working?

Tags: painting, ceiling

I've decided to paint my studio, which is a 770 sq rectangular space.

I'm going to need to paint the ceiling as well as the walls. I'm going to paint the ceiling first then the walls.  I'm going to use a roller for the majority of the work.

Do I need to cover the entire floor before I start painting the ceiling, or can I move the painters cloth as I paint?

I don't want to buy 770 sq feet of painters cloth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule; remove from the area or cover, anything that you don't want to clean later and/or possibly ruin.

Any hardware store should have poly film in large rolls - big enough to cover that entire area for around $20.

Comment: If your floor is something you could easily clean paint from, then you could probably just get away with piling any furniture in the room in the middle and covering it, so long as you clean any drips fairly quickly (so you don't step in them and track them around). If it's something like carpet, or you're a very messy painter, the time and cost to put down some poly film or builder's paper will easily be worth it.